# Calling native code from C#: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I'd like to be able to call functions on an unmanaged C++ DLL from C#. To do this, I'm intending to make a C++ CLR wrapper DLL, which provides the managed implementation that the C# program can call.

I've constructed a minimal solution in Visual Studio to sanity test this arrangement. I have the following projects, all set to build with platform `x64`:

- **UnmanagedLib**: an unmanaged C++ DLL. This simply contains the exported function `int32_t GetMagicNumber()`, and its implementation `return 1234;`.
- **ManagedLib**: the managed C++ CLR wrapper DLL. This contains a `public ref class ManagedFunctions` class with a `static Int32 GetMagicNumber()` function. This function calls `UnmanagedLib::GetMagicNumber()` to fetch the number from the unmanaged DLL.
- **UnmanagedAppLinksToUnmanagedLib**: a simple console application which links to the unmanaged DLL and prints the magic number, to sanity test that the implementation works.
- **ManagedAppLinksToManagedLib**: a simple console application which links to the managed DLL and prints the magic number, to sanity test that the managed DLL links to the unmanaged DLL properly, and returns the correct value.
- **CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib**: a simple C# console application which links to the managed DLL and prints the magic number. If this application is able to function correctly, it means that the whole scenario works.

Everything goes fine until I try to actually use **ManagedLib** from the C# console application:

```
using System;

namespace CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to call managed library...");
            Int32 number = ManagedLib.ManagedFunctions.GetMagicNumber();
            Console.WriteLine("Managed lib magic number: {0}", number);
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, starting the C# application gives the error:

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'ManagedLib, Version=1.0.8021.20195, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'. An attempt was made to load a program with an
> incorrect format.'

This is before anything is even printed to the console, so I'm assuming it's when the application is first started and attempts to load the managed DLL.

Google searches on this error message seem to suggest that the C# application is attempting to load a DLL with a mismatched platform. However, I made sure to explicitly set all projects to `x64` - indeed, I removed the options for `Win32` and `Any CPU` from the configuration manager, and made sure that the C# application project was targeting `x64`.

The projects also have the following settings:

- **UnmanagedLib**: No common language runtime support, no .NET target framework version.
- **ManagedLib**: Common language runtime support, .NET target framework version v4.7.2. As per the comments, I have also tried switching to .NET Core runtime support for .NET Core 3.1, but this doesn't seem to make any difference.
- **CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib**: Target framework .NET Core 3.1 (I have also tried .NET Core 5.0 but this doesn't seem to help)

Output from the debugger:

```
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Interop\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\5.0.12\hostfxr.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\hostpolicy.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\coreclr.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. 
The thread 0x2cd4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\clrjit.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Interop\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Interop\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.dll'
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Interop\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.dll'. 
The thread 0x3418 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Interop\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\System.Runtime.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\System.Console.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\System.Console.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Interop\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ManagedLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll'
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Interop\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ManagedLib.dll'
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Interop\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ManagedLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA2094F69 in CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: HRException at memory location 0x0000005767D8A348.
'CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Interop\CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib\bin\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ManagedLib.dll'
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA2094F69 in CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA2094F69 in CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: HRException at memory location 0x0000005767D8A348.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA2094F69 in CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0000005767D8A7C8.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA2094F69 in CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA2094F69 in CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0000005767D8A7C8.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA2094F69 in CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA2094F69 in CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0000005767D8A7C8.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA2094F69 in CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Could not load file or assembly 'ManagedLib, Version=1.0.8021.21079, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

The program '[20376] CSharpAppLinksToManagedLib.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried a C# app that targets .Net Framework instead of .Net Core?

Comment: Quote: ".NET target framework version v4.7.2".  That indeed is an incorrect format for a .NET Core app.  You'll have to retarget that library.

Comment: I have now set the managed library to ".NET Core runtime support" for ".NET Core 3.1", but this doesn't seem to solve the problem.